# How to create column from a column containing multiple dictionaries in Pyspark

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with samples as follows in a pyspark dataframe:

| id | features |
| --- | --- |
| a | [{"source":"abc","bus_name":"business_342","type":"tpA"},{"source":"pqr","bus_name":"busness_342","type":"tpP"}] |
| b | [{"source":"abc","bus_name":"business_574","type":"tpB"},{"source":"pqr","bus_name":"busness_896","type":"tpQ"}] |
| c | [{"source":"abc","bus_name":"business_112","type":"tpC"},{"source":"pqr","bus_name":"busness_312","type":"tpR"}] |

The schema for the above table is:
id-->string
features-->string

I need to consider values from source='abc' alone in the following format.

| id | source | bus_name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | abc | business_342 | tpA |
| b | abc | business_574 | tpB |
| c | abc | business_112 | tpC |

Please help me with pyspark code for doing this transformation. Thanks

Comment: Can you add schema of the input DF? use `df.printSchema()`

Comment: I have added @RonakJain, Its string for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
schema=ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("source", StringType()),
        StructField("bus_name", StringType()),
        StructField("type", StringType())
]))

df.withColumn("features", F.explode(F.from_json("features", schema)))\
.select("id","features.*")\
.filter(F.col("source")=="abc")\
.show()
```

Input:

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |features                                                                                                        |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|a  |[{"source":"abc","bus_name":"business_342","type":"tpA"},{"source":"pqr","bus_name":"busness_342","type":"tpP"}]|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Full Output:

```
+---+------+------------+----+
| id|source|    bus_name|type|
+---+------+------------+----+
|  a|   abc|business_342| tpA|
|  a|   pqr| busness_342| tpP|
+---+------+------------+----+
```

After Filter (only source = abc)

```
+---+------+------------+----+
| id|source|    bus_name|type|
+---+------+------------+----+
|  a|   abc|business_342| tpA|
+---+------+------------+----+
```